# What should you do when someone questions your question in his answer?

Tags: discussion

Has anyone encountered such a scenario when someone questions your question in his answer? I did encountered this situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741327/transmitting-the-correct-session-data-when-multiple-tabs-are-opened-on-a-web-bro/7741513#7741513) from someone with a high reputation. Though his response did not answer my question, it did lead me to review my work.

What would you do if you encounter such a situation?

Comment: That particular response doesn't seem like an answer to me. In general, I do that frequently, but in comments. If a response doesn't answer your question, let the person know -- whether they are brand new or high rep.

Comment: Flag to moderator with attached reference to your answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes this happens and it's appropriate.  For instance, if someone asks:

> How do I drive a nail with a screwdriver?

it might be appropriate to say

> Actually, it's better to use a hammer for this.  You will break your screwdriver if you drive enough nails with it, and you are likely to ruin your nails or your wall.

You don't always know what you need, and a lot of times the proposed method is either inappropriate, stupid, or dangerous.  Questioning the validity of a question in an answer is appropriate if:

**1** - It's polite
**2** - The answerer explains WHY the premise of the question is incorrect
**3** - They provide an alternate solution or path

In your case, the answer was none of these (arguably he did a little of #2), and it would be appropriate to flag it for moderator attention as `not an answer`.

See also [The XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) which is often related to this.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. For my case, I think I would still tolerate as long as I can see some good intention in it even if the approach is not so appropriate. :)

Comment: Yes, I have found in reviewing that sometimes the premise of the question is *factually false* to the point where it invalidates the question making it a prime case for closure.  Other cases a friendly suggestion is necessary because the premise is poor.